# how to list/ play all music in the :C\music directory

Tags: batch-file

i need some raw batch code for my batch OS to list all the files and play them, as well as ad more directories. 
Help?

Comment: Can you share with us the code you have so far?

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: The above two comments are **completely** correct, however; I will give you some tips to get you started.  ***M3U*** files are nothing more than simple text files with MP3 names in them.  You could list all of the mp3 file names and pipe them to a m3u file.  Then play the m3u file.  Try starting with `for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /s *.mp3') do echo %%f >>mytest.m3u` and take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to play mp3 files (with no external programs installed you can play only MP3 and WAV files through batch file). You can use [soundPlayer.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/mshta/soundPlayer.bat):

```
@echo off

for %%a in ("c:\music\*") do (
   call soundPlayer.bat "%%~fa"
)
```